# CSS Positioning of Input and Dropdown in Data Table

Tags: css, vue.js

I’m working on a data table for an app using `Vue.js`, and I’m running into an issue regarding the position of input elements. The requirement is that certain columns should have editable values via input boxes and dropdowns. However, I’m not able to get the positioning completely correct for some reason. I can align the unmodified component in the row with no problem, but when I modify the value inside the component, it shifts downwards and expands the row. I had to modify the line-height of the row, and I removed the padding on all the row items, to achieve this. Here’s an example:

Before:

[image: Before edit:]

After typing in the text field on the left, clicking away, and then clicking back inside to modify the value:

[image]

After clearing the value and clicking away from the text input, it goes back to its original state. A similar effect happens with the dropdown. Another issue with the dropdown is that the menu is completely blocked by the boundary of the row. I can make the menu visible by removing the “position: relative” styling, but then the component is not aligned, like this:

[image]

Otherwise, it’s just this:

[image]

Notice how the box moves to the top of the row.

I've achieved what I currently have by removing all the padding on elements in the row and then using `top: 8px` to center each component. However, when I check in the Chrome Dev Tools, I see that there is padding even though I set the padding to 0 in all directions (except `padding-right`, which is 8px) from my CSS.

[image]

I really don't know why these issues are happening. What I would like is to have the both the text field and the dropdown to stay put, and for the dropdown items to be visible without them shifting around. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: did you try padding:0 !important ?

Comment: if your div is display:inline-block then please give vertical-align: middle to div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an extra area that was meant for a label above the content of both types of inputs that was generating the extra space and causing the elements to shift. Once I removed that empty label, everything worked fine.